# eclipse + ddms - don't copy timestamp etc from ddms logs?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm using the eclipse plugin for android development. When I copy/paste log contents from ddms, I always get the timestamp etc in the copy/paste:

```
05-16 21:43:09.082: INFO/ActivityManager(110): [message text]
05-16 21:43:09.152: INFO/ActivityManager(110): [message text]
...
```

Is there any way to clip the timestamp + debug level + pid from the paste as seen above, and only get the [message text] copied? It just gets annoying sometimes when sending log details to others as it's a bit noisy for them to look at,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter your logs with this one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/^(.*?: ){2}//'
```

Comment: But you left me thinking. This will do the trick just fine: `adb shell "logcat |grep -vE 's/^(.*?: ){2}//'"`

Comment: duh, I run it on a command prompt and it worked... but I never compared it to the regular adb logcat output... the shell never shows you the timestamp! :/

Answer (score 0):

Write a 5 line program to remove the first 20 characters of each line to remove the timestamp,
or use line.split(" ") to remove the first 3 parts.

Or use a text editor with block selection such as [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/download/index.html)